# Cascade Drop Down List with ajax in MVC 3 Not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am using ajax with cascade drop down list in mvc 3. Here is the code :

```
<script>
function LoadSubCat() {
    var des = $("#CategoryID").val();

    // Call our controller method and process the list of Model objects
    $.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/ProjectController/GetSubCategory")', { Category_ID: des },
        function (subCategory) {
            $("#SubCategory").empty();
            $.each(subCategory, function (i, c) {
                $("#SubCategory").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(c.id).html(c.name)
                );
            });
    });
}
</script>
```

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
</div>
 <div class="editor-label">
    SubCategory
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <select id="SubCategory" onchange="LoadSubCat()"></select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.pjt_Categories, "pjt_Category_ID", "CatName");
    ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.pjt_Statuses, "pjt_Status_ID", "StatusName");

    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetSubCategory(string Category_ID)
{
    // Instantiate our context and do whatever goo we need to select the objects we want
    using (laintranet1Entities ctx = new laintranet1Entities())
    {
        return Json(ctx.pjt_SubCategories.Where(d => d.CategoryID == Category_ID).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, can some one help me because I have to have this finished by this evening. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: what does `subCategory` returns? Did you get the response?

Comment: Nope @DON, the drop down list had no values in it. Sub category will contain topics that has to be done in a IT Section example category = "IT Development" Sub Category = "Software", etc.

Comment: No, I meant to ask what data you getting as response... `function (subCategory)`

Comment: Sorry @DON, what do you mean?

Comment: you're calling `$.getJSON` right, what data you're getting from this ? Try adding this `function (subCategory) { console.log(subCategory); }`

Comment: Where do I put it?

I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899154/3-dropdown-list-cascade-using-mvc3-linqsql) and tried to follow it step by step to try and get it working

Comment: $.getJSON('@Url.Content("~/ProjectController/GetSubCategory")', { Category_ID: des },
        function (subCategory) { console.log(subCategory); }-- remaining code...

Comment: Sorry @DON, silly me. Give me a sec. Still nothing.

Comment: No joy still DON, any other way you might know how to get it working?

Comment: Have a look at this link.. you will get some idea... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230351/post-a-json-data-on-a-server-url-using-javascript/14230389#14230389

Comment: Ok, do I just alter that to get it working?

Comment: yes, you can check my answer there for getting `json` as response on `ajax` request.